# Protect specific files inside folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I used `.htaccess` to protect my admin area and include `index.php` file in all folders with `redirect` script so that no one can list my files inside folder. e.g `Images, css` etc

If someone want to access `http://www.mainDomain/scripts/` it will redirect to `http://www.mainDomain/`

But If someone want to access `http://www.mainDomain/scripts/style.css` how i will redirect(to protect our code from being copied)

Comment: You can't keep your CSS from being copied

Comment: You can do that as long as none of the scripts (js, css, php, etc.) are needed to display the pages of process the data and in that case those files should be out of the web space.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA: The easiest option to protect the `css` file would be to delete it then, right? ;-)

Comment: If it is needed can't be protected. If it is not, should be moved or deleted, yes. Not what I meant, but why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you send to the client when returning a webpage (Usually a combination of html / css and possibly JavaScript) Will be visible and edit-able by the client. You can't protect the transmitted data to prevent people from copying / editying it.

Assuming you need your `style.css` as a stylesheet on (one of) your pages, you can't block users from viewing it. (That would defeat the purpose of having the stylesheet, since you won't be using it then.)

Technically, it is possible to block external addresses from opening the `.css`, while allowing server-side access, but that would also block the file when included in a html page.

Not really the answer you're looking for, I'd wager, but sometimes, you just run into limitations of the software you're working with.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA: Thanks for telling me to "Mind my own business". Very nice. As you can see by the timestamp, Mine was the second answer on here, and the answer was posted __before__ you posted your comment.
The "delete the file" comment was merely a silly / joke suggestion. I don't see what you're so angry about.

Answer (score 3):

CSS is client side language and you can not protect it. If you do not give access to your CSS files to remote browser it simply can not use them to render page.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop someone from hotlinking it but you can't stop them from viewing your css file; well technically you can but that will also disabled you from using it as well.

Answer (score -2):

You can write a file that checks the ip address from the request. If the ip is from the server; allow it, otherwise disallow it? :)